# Count how many items in a DataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this form where textboxes holds a client's education information. I've put these textboxes in array so I can individually call them and put information to them from my datatable. I achieve this using a for loop and counter for it is the amount of rows in the datatable. I was wondering if there's a way to count the amount of items in it so I can change the counter to a much larger value and avoid all these other counters:

```
        TextBox[] arrayE = {
            txtSchoolN1, txtDegree1, txtStartD1, txtEndD1,
            txtSchoolN2, txtDegree2, txtStartD2, txtEndD2,
            txtSchoolN3, txtDegree3, txtStartD3, txtEndD3,
            txtSchoolN4, txtDegree4, txtStartD4, txtEndD4,
            txtSchoolN5, txtDegree5, txtStartD5, txtEndD5,
            txtSchoolN6, txtDegree6, txtStartD6, txtEndD6,
        };
        int[] counter = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            arrayE[counter[0]].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][0].ToString().Trim();
            arrayE[counter[1]].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][1].ToString().Trim();
            arrayE[counter[2]].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][2].ToString().Trim();
            arrayE[counter[3]].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][3].ToString().Trim();
            counter[0] += 4;
            counter[1] += 4;
            counter[2] += 4;
            counter[3] += 4;
        }
```

In a nutshell, I'm trying to shorten my code

Comment: Are you using WPF or Forms?

Comment: I'm using just Forms, sir.

Comment: Idk if it works the same way in WPF, but you can just do like for (int i ... blah bla datatable.Items.Count I think

Comment: I would think you would hit an error with `x <= dataTable.Rows.Count`

Comment: That's a typo. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a second, nested loop:

```
int[] counter = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Rows.Count; x++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter.Length; i++) {
        arrayE[counter[i]].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][i].ToString().Trim();
        counter[i] += 4;
    }
}
```

Or, without the counter array:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Rows.Count; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; i++) {
        arrayE[4 * x + y].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][y].ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this short enough?

```
int countOne = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++)
    {
        arrayE[countOne + y].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][y].ToString().Trim();
    }
    countOne += 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```
var arrayE = new[]
{
    new[] {txtSchoolN1, txtDegree1, txtStartD1, txtEndD1},
    new[] {txtSchoolN2, txtDegree2, txtStartD2, txtEndD2},
    new[] {txtSchoolN3, txtDegree3, txtStartD3, txtEndD3},
    new[] {txtSchoolN4, txtDegree4, txtStartD4, txtEndD4},
    new[] {txtSchoolN5, txtDegree5, txtStartD5, txtEndD5},
    new[] {txtSchoolN6, txtDegree6, txtStartD6, txtEndD6}
};
for (var x = 0; x < dataTable.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    arrayE[x][0].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][0].ToString().Trim();
    arrayE[x][1].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][1].ToString().Trim();
    arrayE[x][2].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][2].ToString().Trim();
    arrayE[x][3].Text = dataTable.Rows[x][3].ToString().Trim();
}
```